# Why intermediate view controllers getting restored?

Tags: ios, iphone, state-restoration

I am using state restoration for my app. 
I have vc1 -> vc2 -> vc3.

On vc3 I have implemented restoration delegates and restoration identifiers. But on vc1 and v2 I implemented identifiers only.

when I reach to vc3 it gets restored that is fine. 
But when I reach to vc2 it also gets restored. and it only has restoration identifier set. Are intermediate viewcontrollers also get restored ? I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically UIKit restores view controllers (including their subviews) that has Reuse Identifiers set. In your case you have set all three view controllers's identifiers. So all your VC's would get restored, even though you have implemented UIStateRestoration methods only for vc3.

You can try removing ReuseID for **vc2** alone and run your app, with **vc3** methods intact with its reuse id. Since your **vc2** does not have a reuse id, UIKit won't care about restoring it. Possible results when you remove reuse id for vc2 would be one of these:

**1. vc3 would be restored, and when you press back button on it, you will directly go to vc1**

**2. Only your vc1 would be restored**